# Array or If statement with a loop for large file. Code works when tested in a small file

Tags: excel, vba

Purpose: Is to have my code to look at Column 4, and find "example 1" or "example 2" or "example 3" and then Return a single value into another cell in column 29. For example D3 is "Example 3" then AC3 is "Value", D1839 is "Example 1" then AC1839 is "Value"

Here is my Code

```
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 1 To FinalRow

        If Cells(x, 4) = "Example 1" Or Cells(x, 4) = "Example 2" Or Cells(x, 4) = "Example 3" _ 
 Or Cells(x, 4) = "Example 4" Or Cells(x, 4) = "Example 5" _
 Or Cells(x, 4) = "Example 6" Then Cells(x, 29) = "AP"
        Next x
```

Oddly enough it works when I try it out on a small sample i.e a new sheet with only Column 4 and 29.

I'm requesting assistance, in finding a method to have the code work. For 65,000 rows with 180 examples.

Thank you for any help. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through an array and build a union of the cells in column AC.

```
Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, rng As Range

arr = Range(Cells(1, "D"), Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

    Select Case arr(i, 1)
        Case "Example 1", "Example 2", "Example 3", "Example 4", "Example 5", "Example 6"
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Cells(i, "AC")
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Cells(i, "AC"))
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

Next i

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng = "AP"
End If
```